# Salvar apenas o ano em um campo date no Postgres! RAILS

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Eu possuo dois campos chamado inicio_ano e termino_ano, no qual quero salvar apenas o ano que o usuário vai selecionar e salvar no banco de dados. Porém quando salva o formulário que é processado pelo RAILS, ele salva ano, mês e dia. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de Saber se consigo salvar um dado de tipo date no Postgres armazenando apenas o ano através do RAILS.

Na pagina Web e basicamente assim que pega os dados 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que no html.erb o codigo está assim
[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]]

No banco de dados existe uma tabela que seria essa que é a criação de user pelo devise.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nessa foto abaixo estão os campos que são adicionados a tabela user, no qual segue os campos inicio_ano e termino_ano

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, você terá que mudar o tipo do campo no banco de dados na sua migration.

### de - (em vez de usar datetime)

```
create_table :nome_da_tabela do |t|
  t.datetime :inicio_ano
  t.datetime :termino_ano
end
```

### Para -  (usar um inteiro)

```
create_table :nome_da_tabela do |t|
  t.integer :inicio_ano
  t.integer :termino_ano
end
```

E na hora de salvar você deve extrair o ano.
Exemplo: `Time.year` retorna `2018`

Comment: No caso eu não posso extrair só o ano do tipo DATE?

Comment: pode sim. Time foi só um exemplo, a syntax é a mesma

Comment: Aonde exatamente eu extraio o ano? Sendo que eu to mexendo no Users do devise

Comment: Edita teu post e cola algum trecho de código, pra gente saber como você tá fazendo.

Comment: Vc pode extrair o ano mas não é o correto. Vc vai disperdiçar armazenamento salvando a data lá, a melhor solução é alterar o campo para inteiro.

Comment: Entendi Alex Takitani, mas eu nao sei como fazer um select que mostre os anos e salve um inteiro